# How kafka stream allocate events?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka stream app that listens to two topics. If two Kafka topics have the same key and the same partition count, will an event with the same key always go to one stream thread (fixed number of stream threads)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such guarantee.

The brokers that hold the leader of those partitions with those keys could be different, and thus assigned to different consumer threads.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee that an event E1 in topic T1 with Key K1 and an event E2 in topic T2 with Key K2 both will be processed by same Stream thread always.

Kafka streams allocates partitions to stream threads, and not events.

**Allocation of partitions in Kafka streams:**

Suppose your input topics, T1 and T2 have 3 partitions each - namely 
T1P0 (1st partition of topic T1)
T1P1 (2nd partition of topic T2)
T1P2 and similarly for Topic T2.

Suppose there are two consumers - each running 2 threads each - let's suppose the name of threads will be C1-0, C1-1, C2-0, C2-1.

Once Kafka stream application restarts, it goes to rebalancing stage where it discovers two things:
1. Number of consumers in the stream topology and finds the name of the threads of all consumers
2. Number of input partitions (across all topics) in the topology.

It then distributes all the partitions to the threads. There are two partition assignment strategies at present : Range and RoundRobin.

1. **Range:**

Range partition assignment strategy lays out the available partitions in numeric order and consumer threads in lexicographic order. Then the number of partitions is divided by the number of consumer threads to determine how many partitions each consumer thread should hold.

In above example - the final partition assignment will look like:
C1-0 will get partitions T1P0, T1P1
C1-1 will get partitions T1P2, T2P0
C2-0 will get partitions T2P1
C2-1 will get partitions T2P2

Range partition assignment strategy is the default strategy used by Kafka Streams to allocate partitions.

In this case - E1 in topic T1 with Key K1 will always go to T1P0 and E2 in topic T2 with Key K2 can always go to T2P0 - both these partitions are allocated to different stream threads.

2. **Round Robin**

Round robin strategy sorts the topic-partition pairs (T1P0, T1P1 etc.) by their hashcode to reduce the possibility of all partitions of one topic to be assigned to one consumer or 1 stream thread.
Then the sorted topic-partition pairs are assigned in a round robin manner to available consumer threads.

In above example - the final partition assignment will look like:
C1-0 will get partitions T1P0, T2P1
C1-1 will get partitions T1P1, T2P2
C2-0 will get partitions T1P2
C2-1 will get partitions T2P0

In this case also, since T1P0 and T2P0 are allocated to different stream thread, E1 and E2 having same key will be processed by different partitions.